# Reading Geospatial Raster files with GDAL and OpenCV3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv, gdal

I'm trying to implement and run OpenCV sample code [Reading Geospatial Raster files with GDAL](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d73/tutorial_raster_io_gdal.html#gsc.tab=0)

For DEM model, i download `N37W123.hgt.zip` from the [SRTM file located at the USGS](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM1/Region_04/N37W123.hgt.zip) , (that is in the Results section of that page).

but, DEM model not loaded to `cv::Mat dem` by `cv::Mat dem = cv::imread(argv[2], cv::IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH );` and i get run time error `throw std::runtime_error("DEM image type must be CV_16SC1");`

1) Why is this happening?

2) All DEM data type are 16 signed integer. is it ok?

3) How can read DEM model block with `GDALDataset::RasterIO` or `GDALRasterBand::ReadBlock` directly?

Answer (score 0):

`gdal` is most likely expecting an HGT file, not a ZIP file: [Link](https://gdal.org/formats_list.html).

In Python you would extract the archive first using the `zipfile` module, then you can access the file directly into a `numpy` array:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(filename)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
```

---

EDIT: You've pointed out in a comment that you are using C++, so see the tutorial for reading the image directly: [Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)

Comment: @ Benjamin `ReadAsArray` is for python. in C++ we can use `RasterIO`or `ReadBlock` functions. DEM data type are `CV_16S` or `CV_32F`.

Comment: You should tag your question with C++, then. Regardless of the language, my point is that GDAL does not read zip files (with a few exceptions), and that you don't need OpenCV to load a file using GDAL. It would be easier to troubleshoot the issue if you removed a layer (OpenCV) and tried the more basic approach first. http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html

Comment: @ Benjamin I know that GDAL could not load zip file. I load a TIFF image with GDAL and save to OpenCV Mat. but for DEM file like .hgt or .TIFF i could not use `IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL` and `cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` that is in `OpenCV3.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely you have to enable/set WITH_GDAL flag to true in CMake while building opencv.
for reference:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#imread